# How to pass page Id correctly in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, dom

In my AllSong.php page, I displayed all the songs title that I have from MySQL database. When ever user click on a particular title, it'll take to that song detail page.

Currently it can navigate to the details page but how the song Id displaying in the url is not correct. The Id is always 13 for some reason so Any suggestion or help will be really appreciated.

So right now, I'm getting like this when it navigate to Details.php page

```
http://localhost:8888/page/details.php?id=13
```

Instead of their correct id

Allsong.php

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM song ORDER BY title ASC";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

// fetch all rows
$songs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

                    <form action="details.php?id=<?= $song['id'] ?>" method="post" hidden>
                        <input type="text" name="search" id="search2"
                            class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-0 border-primary width =250px;"
                            placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" required="">
                        <input type="submit" id='searchclick' name="submit" value="Search"
                            class="btn btn-primary rounded-right">
                    </form>
```

My details page

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $title = $_POST['search'];
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM song WHERE title = :title';
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(['title' => $title]);
  $row = $stmt->fetch();

} elseif (!empty($_REQUEST['id'])) {
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM song WHERE id = :id';
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(['id' => $_REQUEST['id']]);
  $row = $stmt->fetch();
} else {
  header('location: .');
  exit();
}
?>
```

Output

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 4 [number] => 3 [title] => I hngilh lo na dawatnak in [chord] => Db [lyrics] => C G Am F When I find myself in times of trouble, Mother Mary comes to me C G F C/E Dm C Speaking words of wisdom, let it be C G Am F And in my hour of darkness, She is standing right in front of me C G F C/E Dm C Speaking words of wisdom, let it be Am G F C Let it be, let it be, let it be, let it be G F C/E Dm C Whisper words of wisdom, let it be [pdf] => PDF-61d2bb72052708.42326233.pdf [ppt] => PPTX-61d2bb720551c1.67609911.pptx [pro] => PRO-61d2bb72058393.63836622.pptx [count] => 18 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 18 [number] => 25 [title] => 1000 [chord] => G [lyrics] => This is just testing text [pdf] => PDF-623c0127de8981.90516888.pdf [ppt] => PPTX-623c0127deb4d2.47792226.pptx [pro] => PRO-623c0127ded5e3.52791215.pro [count] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [number] => 4 [title] => Bawipa Thangthat [chord] => G [lyrics] => {key:C} Verse 1 [G2] You said there will [D/F#]be a da[Em]y When the captives [D]all go free [Asus/C#] And every [Bm7]war will cease [G2] You said there will [D/F#]come a ti[Em]me When the nations of the world will [D]change their minds And be [Asus/C#]led by a [Bm7]little child [pdf] => PDF-61d2bbe5467a42.53452418.pdf [ppt] => PPTX-61d2bbe546a234.50867723.pptx [pro] => PRO-61d2bbe546c3b7.71654144.pptx [count] => 0 )
```

Comment: "When ever user click" is a clue. Is your code passing this id on "onclick"? ... Ok, you have php var `$song` which you never declare anywhere. You define `$songs` in your loop, but you dont define `song` singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Allsong.php, you have to use foreach in order for the id-s to change for each song.

```
    <?php
    require_once '../config.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM song ORDER BY title ASC";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    // fetch all rows
    $songs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?>

<?php
foreach ($songs as $song) { 
        foreach ($song as $s) {
    ?>
        <form action="details.php?id=<?= $s['id'] ?>" method="post" hidden>
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search2"
                class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-0 border-primary width =250px;"
                placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" required="">
            <input type="submit" id='searchclick' name="submit" value="Search"
                class="btn btn-primary rounded-right">
        </form>
<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: Hi @Arian, thank you for this but som reason now the Id turn to 4 always. it's still not displaying the their correct id for some reason.

Comment: Hey @ziico, What do you get if you do a print_r($songs); can you tell me if there are different id-s ?

Comment: yes there are different id. I attached the the sample  output in my post. pls check. thanks

Comment: Hey @ziico, can you check my updated answer.

Comment: sadly, it's still didn't work. Now the id is missing. it didn't show any number at all. :(

Comment: @ziico check it out now, hopefully this works.